# Power Bi Embedded Parameter - Space in Column Name

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop

I'm using a Power BI Dashboard Embedded in my application. So I'm passing some Parameters to it from the URL in the following structure

> https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=MyReportId&groupId=ReportGroupId&autoAuth=true&$filter=User/User
>   id+eq+'1234'

The issue I'm facing here is that the column name **User Id** has a space in it and hence the filter is not working as expected. My data source is an SSAS cube and I don't have permission to edit the same.

Is there any alternative solutions for this?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: btw you don't need to quote the numbers (and even dates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-url-filters#special-characters-in-url-filters), special characters and spaces must be escaped with `_xuuuu_`, where `uuuu` is the unicode value of the character. So `User Id` must be escaped as `User_x0020_Id`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. It's working as expected now

Comment: great anwser, thx. ps. Don't forget the 'x':  User_x0020_Id